# Корректно завершать работу программы по сигналу

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Задача стоит такая:
Корректно завершать работу программы по сигналу.

Пока что информации никакой не нашел (рабочей). Или я что-то тестирую не так, или в sun опять что-то намудрили.

P.S. Пишу на 8 версии

Comment: java уже давно как Oracle занимается, а не Sun

Comment: > P.S. Пишу на 8 версии

Гм. Но ведь её релиз лишь 14 марта ожидается. А последний релиз Java — 7.51.

Answer (score 1):

Примеров полно, например:  "[java exit signal handling](http://peymanp.blogspot.ru/2007/10/java-exit-signal-handeling.html)"

P.S. не рано ли вы на 8ю жаву пересели?